# How to pass a dynamically generated ID to Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using a nice [Jquery context menu](http://www.planitworks.nl/en/jeegoocontext) which returns the ID of my element in the form

```
$(context).attr('id')
```

and not in the form

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

due to the fact that I'm using one single context menu for a large number of elements where each element has its unique ID. The context menu works perfectly as it executes the commands relative to the clicked element identified by its unique ID.

I use the context menu to write data to a MySQl db via $.get and this works too.

But now I would like to use the data I get back from $.get and use it with the .replaceWith method to change some text without refreshing the page:

```
$.get("jq_get_go.php", { parameter2: $(this).attr('menuCommand'), id: $(context).attr('id') }, 
    function(data) {
        $(".ci_saremo").xxxxx.replaceWith('<li class="Like ci_saremo" id="' + $(context).attr('id') + '"><a href="">' + data + '</a></li>');
    }
);
```

I don't understand what should I replace the xxxxx with to get the ID of my element that I know I have here

```
$(context).attr('id')
```

Of course if I omit xxxxx and leave

```
$(".ci_saremo").replaceWith('<li class="Like ci_saremo" id="' + $(context).attr('id') + '"><a href="">' + data + '</a></li>');
```

every ".ci_saremo" text will be replaced. So I need to identify it by its ID. Basically, I don't understand how to chain/insert `$(context).attr('id')` in the above string.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$('#'+$(context).attr('id')).replaceWith...
```

Comment: This suggestion does display the string, but it does not replace the string I want. The new string is printed in a different area of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your intentions, but it looks as if you're trying to replace the `link` text inside of the `li` item. If so, you should be able to do this:

```
$(context).
    .find(".ci_saremo")
    .replaceWith('<li class="Like ci_saremo" id="' + $(context).attr('id') + '"><a href="">' + data + '</a></li>');
```

The find method will grab the `.ci_saremo` elements *within* `$(context).attr('id')`. This should isolate the single element you want to change.

**EDITED**

Comment: `$(context).attr('id')` returns a string, so `.find` doesn't work.  Also, I think he has a bunch of elements with class `ci_saremo` and wants the one with that specific ID.

Comment: Yes Rocket, I have a number of elements with class `ci_saremo` and I want to get one with a specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

If `$(context).attr('id')` returns the ID, doesn't that mean that `context` is your element?

If so, couldn't you just do this?

```
$(context).replaceWith('<li class="Like ci_saremo" id="' + $(context).attr('id') + '"><a href="">' + data + '</a></li>');
```

Comment: I use a icon that clicked displays the context menu. If I use your suggestion, the icon is replaced by the string. I guess `$(context)` identifies the icon which has the ID of the element I want to change.

Comment: @Nicero: My guess is that both the icon, and the element have the same ID (because `$(context).attr('id')` gets the correct ID).  Try to change one of the IDs to something different.  Or, you can try this: `var id = $(context).attr('id');  $('#'+id+'.ci_saremo').replaceWith(`.  Though, I suggest fixing the IDs so there are no duplicates.

Comment: OK! I've got it! As ID are generated by PHP I added the ID to the calss name (i.e. ci_saremo5981) in this way the class name is unique. Then I wrote `var id = $(context).attr('id'); $('.ci_saremo'+id).replaceWith` and the replaceWith method now changes only that element. Thank you.

Comment: @Nicero: Glad I could help :-D